# Rails: Validate input without need of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Let's say that I have an input field with a value, and I want to validate it (on the server side) to make sure, for instance, that the field has at least 5 characters.

The problem is that it is not something that I want to save in the database, or build a model. I just want to check that the value validates.

In PHP with Laravel, validation is quite easy:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => ['required', 'email'],
    'message' => ['required']]);

if ($validator->fails()) { // Handle it... }
```

Is there anything similar in Rails, without need of ActiveRecord, or ActiveModel? Not every data sent from a form makes sense as a Model.

Comment: Why not use javascript validation in the form and use form object

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects.

It will help you reuse the form and its logic at other places if necessary.

Comment: Client-side validation can be manipulated by the user, is not reliable

Comment: About that link you added, it requires that the information you are posting can be defined as a resource (which is basically the same as defining a model). I am looking for validation without that much fuzz. Simple and direct, like in the PHP example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use ActiveModel::Validations like this

```
class MyClass
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :message, presence: true
end
```

It will act as a normal model and you will be able to do `my_object.valid?` and `my_object.errors`.

Comment: As I said in the question, is there a way to make it without Models? Not every set of data sent through a form is meant to be a model.

Comment: This is not a model, this is a class. This is the ruby way. If you have a complex things to do, you will do it a class. Ruby is a really oriented object language.

Comment: So there isnt any way or Validation Helper to make validations in a simple direct way?

Comment: The only other way to do it I see is to do it manually but I don't see a reason to not use a class.

Comment: Well, depends on the nature of the webapp. If it is a form-heavy webapps, some Classes may seem form like `Class QuestionType24`. It just makes not much sense...

Comment: @Dbugger: If you do not want class for this, where do you want to store that logic than? In the controllers? Than it is much harder to test and maintain.

Comment: That would depend maybe on the nature of the application. In any case, I want to know if it is doable.

Comment: I have created a validation class as per above however how do I now link it's to my controller so validate the form data supplied?

Answer (score 5):

Rails validations live in `ActiveModel` so doing it without `ActiveModel` seems kind of counter-productive. Now, if you can loosen that requirement a bit, it is definitely possible.

What I read you asking for, and as I read the PHP code doing, is a validator-object that can be configured on the fly.

We can for example build a validator class dynamically and use instance of that class to run our validations. I have opted for an API that looks similar to the PHP one here:

```
class DataValidator
  def self.make(data, validations)
    Class.new do
      include ActiveModel::Validations

      attr_reader(*validations.keys)

      validations.each do |attribute, attribute_validations|
        validates attribute, attribute_validations
      end

      def self.model_name
        ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "DataValidator::Validator")
      end

      def initialize(data)
        data.each do |key, value|
          self.instance_variable_set("@#{key.to_sym}", value)
        end
      end
    end.new(data)
  end
end
```

Using `DataValidator.make` we can now build instances of classes with the specific validations that we need. For example in a controller:

```
validator = DataValidator.make(
  params,
  {
    :email => {:presence => true},
    :name => {:presence => true}
  }
)
if validator.valid?
  # Success
else
  # Error
end
```

Comment: Good point, I just want to ask, where would I basically add this class? Is it better to add this under controller or model?

Comment: I guess that's a matter of preference more than anything. It's not a controller, so that's probably not the right place. It's not really a business object either, so `app/models` might not be the best place. `lib` is an existing alternative, or you could create `app/validators` or some such.

Comment: @JakobS - thank you for your answer + cool metaprogramming. What is the significance of using `Class.new do.....end.New()`? What is that doing, and why are you doing it that way? Can't see do everything that the above code is doing simply by ommitting `Class.new do....end` and pasting everything directly in the `DataValidator` class?

Comment: So `Class.new {}` returns a new class and the subsequent `.new(data)` returns an instance of that class, which means that `DataValidator.make` returns an instance that you can call `valid?` on.

You cannot copy/paste the contents of the block into a new class, because the contents depend on 2 arguments, although I'd love to be proven wrong :)

It's a dynamic and more complex way of doing what's hardcoded in [Douguis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25460413/33245), which actually does what the original PHP code did; namely build a validator object.